# Excel Array Evaluation and some tricks

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, evaluation

I came across some array evaluation tricks on the net. But i couldn't understand the theory. I think there are many like me who want to know about this subject.

- what is array evaluation and why do we need that?
- how does **`N( INDEX (.....))`** trick work behind the scenes?
- how does **`N( IF (1,.....))`** trick work behind the scenes?
- why do we need to use **`N function`** here?

Answer (score 2):

1. Write the formula.
2. Select it.
3. Go to the ribbon and select Formula>Evaluate
4. Click <kbd>Evaluate</kbd> and see for yourself

[image]

Comment: "Formula>Evaluate" doesn't give much information to my questions above.